# How to use props outside the class?

Tags: reactjs, mqtt

I'm using mqtt-react to subscribe 'Card_sens' component to a specific topic. This topic is dynamic and is a combination of two props passed to 'Card_sens'.
The problem is that i cannot access props outside the 'Card_sens' class.

Any idea ho to handle this?

I searched for similar questions but didn't find anything relevant.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { subscribe } from 'mqtt-react';
var global_id_a='';
var global_id_s='';

class Card_sens extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     global_id_a=this.props.id_a;
     global_id_s=this.props.key;
}

  render(){
  return(
  <Card key={this.props.key}>
    <Card.Content >
      <Card.Header >
      <Icon name='code' size='large' />  {this.props.name}
      </Card.Header>
  </Card>
)
}
}

export default subscribe({
  topic: 'data/#' + global_id_a + '/' + global_id_s     //this doesn't work 
})(Card_sens)
```

**EDIT**
I use the subscribed exported Card_sens component like this:

```
<Card_Sens key={sensore.id_sens} id_a={sensore.id_a} />
```

Adding a functional component as a wrapper:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Card, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react'
    import { subscribe } from 'mqtt-react';

   const Wrapper = (props) => {

    id_a= props.id_a;
    key= props.key;
        class Card_sens extends Component {

         render(){
          return(
          <Card key={this.props.key}>
            <Card.Content >
              <Card.Header >
              <Icon name='code' size='large' />  {this.props.name}
              </Card.Header>
          </Card>
        )
        }
        }

        export default subscribe({
          topic: 'data/#' + id_a + '/' + key     //this doesn't work either. ERROR: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
        })(Card_sens)
    }
```

And doing something like this:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Card, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react'
    import { subscribe } from 'mqtt-react';

   const Wrapper = (props) => {

    id_a= props.id_a;
    key= props.key;
        class Card_sens extends Component {

         render(){
          return(
          <Card key={this.props.key}>
            <Card.Content >
              <Card.Header >
              <Icon name='code' size='large' />  {this.props.name}
              </Card.Header>
          </Card>
        )
        }
        }

        return subscribe({
          topic: 'data/#' + id_a + '/' + key    
           })(Card_sens)
        }
export default Wrapper
```

returns this two errors:

- Warning: Wrapper(...): A valid React element (or null) must be
  returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other
  invalid object.
- Uncaught Error: Wrapper(...): A valid React element
  (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array
  or some other invalid object.

It seems like it returns not an element if you use `subscribe({topic: 'data/#'})(Card_sens)` **not** at the top level of the file.
If you use `subscribe({topic: 'data/#'})(Card_sens)` at the top level of the file it returns a valid element and everything works(but i cannot dinamically subscribe to topics this way)
I'm getting confused.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say because documentation of **mqtt-react** does not saying nothing about that. I suppose you can achieve the goal by adding additional functional component as a wrapper. Example:

```
export default ({id_a, key}) => subscribe({
  topic: 'data/#' + id_a+ '/' + key
})(<Card_sens id_a={id_a} key={key}/>);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had the same idea at the beginning but when wrapping the original component (Card_sens) into a functional component i can't export the original component inside the wrapper because import/export must be done only at top level. And if i try to return the subscribe function and then exporting the wrapper, i get an error from React saying the wrapper must return a valid React element (or null). If any doubt, please ask.

Comment: If you can provide a working example that would be very useful. Maybe i'm missing something :)

Comment: @Stramike I have change example a little bit, I am passing the props to the Card_sens. Can you check that approach?

Comment: I checked different solutions and edited the post to show the errors i'm getting.